# 2.5D Matrix wah's and Video Cards

Tags: c#, 3d, matrix, xna

I am a capital 'N' noob when it comes to 3D. With that said, I have been trying to get my 2.5 game view working. Works for me on a NVIDIA ,but not my friend on a ATI.  He either see's nothing or if the Z value of a triangle is not 0 he doesnt see it.
I am guessing its not the video cards fault and maybe some video cards are more forgiving then others. Heres my code:

```
basicEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;  
basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographic(-camera.Size.X,- camera.Size.Y,-1000, 1000);  
basicEffect.View =  Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(camera.Position.X,camera.Position.Y ,-10)  
, new Vector3(camera.Position.X, camera.Position.Y, 10),  
 Vector3.Up) * Matrix.CreateScale(camera.Zoom);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answered here on the XNA forum [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/71761.aspx).